if any one of the input sensors fail, it should stop at start - DAG should fail
I have a dag where I have a task called start which is a dummy operator . Before the start I have a few input sensors for checking the file . I need to run the DAG for test cases .

all the input sensors are success, start and downstream should run - DAG should be success
2)if any one of the input sensors fail, DAG should stop at start , the downstream tasks after start should get skipped and the DAG should fail

enter image description here
all the input sensors are success, start and downstream should run - DAG should be success
if any one of the input sensors fail, it should stop at start and the downstream tasks after start should be skipped and DAG should fail
